# Pyspark display max value(S) and multiple sorting

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Grateful for some help here. Using Pyspark (cannot use SQL please). So I have a list of tuples stored as RDD Pairs:

> [(('City1', '2020-03-27', 'X1'), 44),
>
> (('City1', '2020-03-28', 'X1'), 44),
>
> (('City3', '2020-03-28', 'X3'), 15),
>
> (('City4', '2020-03-27', 'X4'), 5),
>
> (('City4', '2020-03-26', 'X4'), 4),
>
> (('City2', '2020-03-26', 'X2'), 14),
>
> (('City2', '2020-03-25', 'X2'), 4),
>
> (('City4', '2020-03-25', 'X4'), 1),
>
> (('City1', '2020-03-29', 'X1'), 1),
>
> (('City5', '2020-03-25', 'X5'), 15)]

With for example ('City5', '2020-03-25', 'X5') as the Key, and 15 as the value of the last pair.

I would like to obtain the following outcome:

> City1, X1, 2020-03-27, 44
>
> City1, X1, 2020-03-28, 44
>
> City5, X3, 2020-03-25, 15
>
> City3, X3, 2020-03-28, 15
>
> City2, X2, 2020-03-26, 14
>
> City4, X4, 2020-03-27, 5

Please notice that the outcome displays:

- The Key(s) with the max value for each city (That's the hardest part, to display same city twice if they have similar max(values) in different dates, I'm assuming cannot use ReduceByKey() as Key is not unique, maybe GroupBy() or Filter() ?
- In the following sequencing of order/sorting:

1. Descending largest value
2. Ascending date
3. Descending city name (ex: City1)

So I have tried the following code:

```py
res = rdd2.map(lambda x: ((x[0][0],x[0][2]), (x[0][1], x[1])))
rdd3 = res.reduceByKey(lambda x1, x2: max(x1, x2, key=lambda x: x[1]))
rdd4 = rdd3.sortBy(lambda a: a[1][1], ascending=False)
rdd5 = rdd4.sortBy(lambda a: a[1][0])
```

Although it does give me the cities with the max value, it doesn't return the same city twice (because reduced by Key: City) if 2 cities has similar max value in 2 different dates.

I hope its clear enough, any precision please ask!
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

To keep all cities with value equals to max value, you can still use `reduceByKey` but over arrays instead of over values:

- you transform your rows into key/value, with value being an array of tuple instead of a tuple
- you reduce by key, merging arrays if they contain the same value, else keeping array that has the max value, with `reduceByKey`
- you flatten your value arrays, merging the key with them, with `flatMap`
- finally you perform your sort

Complete code would be as follows:

```py
def merge(array1, array2):
    if array1[0][2] > array2[0][2]:
        return array1
    elif array1[0][2] == array2[0][2]:
        return array1 + array2
    else:
        return array2


res = rdd2.map(lambda x: (x[0][0], [(x[0][1], x[0][2], x[1])]))
rdd3 = res.reduceByKey(lambda x1, x2: merge(x1, x2))
rdd4 = rdd3.flatMap(lambda x: map(lambda y: (x[0], y[1], y[0], y[2]), x[1]))
rdd5 = rdd4.sortBy(lambda a: (-a[3], a[2], a[0]))
```

And then you can print your RDD:

```
[print(', '.join([row[0], row[1], row[2], str(row[3])])) for row in rdd5.collect()]
```

That, with your input, gives you the following output:

```
City1, X1, 2020-03-27, 44
City1, X1, 2020-03-28, 44
City5, X5, 2020-03-25, 15
City3, X3, 2020-03-28, 15
City2, X2, 2020-03-26, 14
City4, X4, 2020-03-27, 5
```

Comment: Thats great @Vincent Doba ! 2 last things: 

the results comes out as "City4, 2020-03-27, x4, 5" instead of "City4, X4, 2020-03-27, 5". The order is fine up to reduceByKey. Been playing around with the flatMap order (x[0] -> x[1], etc..) but the result doesnt change, so Im suspecting the merge function is where the order is incorrect ?

Comment: Also, the output comes out with a brackets (tuple) in the form of: (City4, X4, 2020-03-27, 5), how do remove the brackets ? I tried parallelize but doesnt work.

Comment: @JohnDoe34 I reordered the rows in the result. You were right, you have to play with flatMap order. For tuple issue, I need some precisions: what do you expect as output ? A string with all fields concatenated ? Because you can only have one type in rdd, either a string, a value, a tuple, an object or an array.

Answer (score 0):

Can you work/output with Dataframes?

```
List = [(('City1', '2020-03-27', 'X1'), 44),
        (('City1', '2020-03-28', 'X1'), 44),
        (('City3', '2020-03-28', 'X3'), 15),
        (('City4', '2020-03-27', 'X4'), 5),
        (('City4', '2020-03-26', 'X4'), 4),
        (('City2', '2020-03-26', 'X2'), 14),
        (('City2', '2020-03-25', 'X2'), 4),
        (('City4', '2020-03-25', 'X4'), 1),
        (('City1', '2020-03-29', 'X1'), 1),
        (('City5', '2020-03-25', 'X5'), 15)]

rdd = sc.parallelize(List)

import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = rdd\
        .toDF()\
        .select('_1.*', F.col('_2').alias('value'))\
        .orderBy(F.desc('value'), F.asc('_2'), F.desc('_1'))

df.show(truncate=False)

+-----+----------+---+-----+
|_1   |_2        |_3 |value|
+-----+----------+---+-----+
|City1|2020-03-27|X1 |44   |
|City1|2020-03-28|X1 |44   |
|City5|2020-03-25|X5 |15   |
|City3|2020-03-28|X3 |15   |
|City2|2020-03-26|X2 |14   |
|City4|2020-03-27|X4 |5    |
|City2|2020-03-25|X2 |4    |
|City4|2020-03-26|X4 |4    |
|City4|2020-03-25|X4 |1    |
|City1|2020-03-29|X1 |1    |
+-----+----------+---+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Luiz but i really need to find a solution not using dataframes sql, instead using python with RDD's transformations & actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your rdd to a [dataframe](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.html) and then use a [Spark's window](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-window-functions/) to get max value for each city, filter rows using this value and finally order your dataframe as you wish:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

window = Window.partitionBy('City').rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

df = rdd.toDF().select(
 F.col('_1._1').alias('city'),
 F.col('_1._2').alias('date'),
 F.col('_1._3').alias('key'),
 F.col('_2').alias('value'),
).withColumn('max_value', F.max('value').over(window))\
 .filter(F.col('value') == F.col('max_value'))\
 .drop('max_value')\
 .orderBy(F.desc('value'), F.asc('date'), F.asc('city'))
```

And you get the following dataframe with your input rdd:

```
+-----+----------+---+-----+
|city |date      |key|value|
+-----+----------+---+-----+
|City1|2020-03-27|X1 |44   |
|City1|2020-03-28|X1 |44   |
|City5|2020-03-25|X5 |15   |
|City3|2020-03-28|X3 |15   |
|City2|2020-03-26|X2 |14   |
|City4|2020-03-27|X4 |5    |
+-----+----------+---+-----+
```

If you need a RDD at the end of process, you can retrieve it using `.rdd` method:

```py
df.rdd
```