# Spark.sql Filter rows by MAX

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Below is part of a source file which you could imagine being much bigger:

```
date,code1,postcode,cityname,total
2020-03-27,2011,X700,Curepipe,44
2020-03-29,2011,X700,Curepipe,44
2020-03-26,2011,X700,Curepipe,22
2020-03-27,2035,X920,vacoas,3
2020-03-25,2011,X920,vacoas,1
2020-03-24,2122,X760,souillac,22
2020-03-23,2122,X760,souillac,11
2020-03-22,2257,X760,souillac,10
2020-03-27,2480,X510,rosehill,21
2020-03-22,2035,X510,rosehill,7
2020-03-20,2035,X510,rosehill,3
```

After the following code:

```py
#Load data
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("source").getOrCreate()
dfcases = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("sourcefile.csv")

dfcases.createOrReplaceTempView("tablecases")
spark.sql(XXXXXXXXXXXXX).show() #Mysql code to insert
```

I would like to obtain this result:

```
Curepipe,X700,2020-03-27,44
Curepipe,X700,2020-03-29,44
souillac,X760,2020-03-24,22
rosehill,X510,2020-03-27,21
vacoas,X920,2020-03-27,3
```

The aim is to:

1. Select the dates which each cityname has the MAX total (Note, A city can appear twice if they have MAX total for 2 different dates),
2. Sort by total descending, then date ascending, then cityname ascending.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it the SQL version of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70181393/pyspark-display-max-values-and-multiple-sorting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your result using a [SQL window](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-window.html) in your request, as follows:

```sql
SELECT
  cityname, 
  postcode, 
  date, 
  total
FROM
 (SELECT 
    cityname, 
    postcode, 
    date, 
    total, 
    MAX(total) OVER (PARTITION BY cityname ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS max_total 
  FROM tablecases)
WHERE max_total = total
ORDER BY max_total DESC, date, cityname
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent, PARTITION BY worked, Thats the solution I found:
```spark.sql("SELECT name, postcode, date, total FROM (SELECT *, MAX(total) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS maxtotal FROM table2) WHERE total = maxtotal ORDER BY total DESC, date, name DESC")```

Answer (score 0):

The following query generates the output you want

```
SELECT cityname, postcode, date, COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM tablecases 
GROUP BY cityname, postcode, date 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, date, cityname
```

Demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c32d270c67c27309a673cffd17d82301)

Comment: Yes, I understand, that's why I used "HAVING COUNT(*) > 1. You do not need the max function with grouping and the post query produces the desired result.

Comment: see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c32d270c67c27309a673cffd17d82301

Comment: Yes you can edit but it gives you a new link

Comment: I have edited the post to make it more comprehensible and closer to the real issue, thanks!